# Software center is broken and can not be repaired or reinstalled

Tags: wine, package-management, dependencies

When I open the software center, I am told that I can not use it, for it is broken, and needs to be repaired. First I try to do this automatically, as I was offered. I enter a root password, and then the installation fails.

```
    installArchives() failed: reconfiguring packages...
reconfiguring packages...
reconfiguring packages...
reconfiguring packages...
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 275048 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking wine1.4-i386 (from .../wine1.4-i386_1.4-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/wine1.4-i386_1.4-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/wine', which is also in package wine1.5 1.5.5-0ubuntu1~ppa1~oneiric1+pulse17
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/wine1.4-i386_1.4-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.4-common:
 wine1.4-common depends on wine1.4 (= 1.4-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package wine1.4 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing wine1.4-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

What should I do now? First of all, I've tried reinstalling the center, but it failed due to the same 1.4 dependency as is laid out here. I've googled for help and although I don't understand linux at all, I've tried some suggestions: I've tried editing the dpkg status in /var/lib/dpkg/status which failed because the file could not be found. I've tried purging wine/* but that had unresolved dependencies as well. It's a giant mess.

Comment: How did you install wine1.4? Did you download a deb file or did you install it from the normal repositories?

Comment: I am not sure, I think 1.4 was installed by deb file, but I can not guarantee this.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get -f install`. If it doesn't solve the problem try `sudo apt-get autoclean`. Third I would try `sudo apt-get autoremove wine1.4`.

Comment: First one failed, tell me if you need more information: dpkg: error processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/wine1.4-i386_1.4-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to rewrite file: „/usr/bin/wine“, which is also in package wine1.5 1.5.5-0ubuntu1~ppa1~oneiric1+pulse17
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Pipe interrupted (SIGPIPE))
Errors occurred in processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/wine1.4-i386_1.4-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Second one: created a list of dependencies and was done. Third one: tells me unresolved dependencies and to run sudo apt-get -f install

Comment: Try `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`. See if there are any lines that refer to wine and delete those lines. Then `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: You might also try `sudo dpkg --purge wine1.4`

Comment: Thank you for being so patient. I suspect editing the sources list is likely the solution, but when I execute the command, it opens up text editor with two tabs and while the first one is general instructions and notes, the second one is not loading/loading endlessly. Very strange, I ran sudo dpkg --purge wine1.4 and it did uninstall wine 1.4. Now the error while trying to repair the software center is: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.4-common:
 wine1.4-common depends on wine1.4 (= 1.4-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package wine1.4 is not installed.

Comment: The sources.list tab that has been opened as first, and which I thought to note merely general instructions does not list wine anywhere.

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/a/121974/27968

Comment: It says "Can not remove '/var/lib/apt/lists': it is a directory"

Comment: When I try to run the update manager as the second solution, it offers me partial upgrade straight away, when I refuse it says software list is damaged and I best run sudo apt-get -f install :D

Comment: Should I try the partial upgrade?

Comment: Did you try removing ppas from the software list as mentioned in the second solution?

Comment: When I try to open the software manager, I am told to partially upgrade the system. When I click "cancel" I am told the software list is damaged, and am recommended to run sudo apt-get -f install. Then the update manager closes.

Comment: To remove ppas open "Software Sources".

Comment: I have executed the apt-get update successfuly as described in the guide of the second solution, nevertheless the software center has the same error as described in initial post.